# Writing test for Spree, cant create variants for products

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, spree

I'm trying to write rspec tests for my spree customizations and i need to create products with variants. i cant seem to do this even though i appear to be doing the exact same thing as the rspec tests that are part of spree core.

```
def build_option_type_with_values(name, values)
  ot = create(:option_type, :name => name)
  values.each do |val|
    ot.option_values.create(:name => val.downcase, :presentation => val)
  end
  ot
end


let(:number_size_option_type) do
  size = build_option_type_with_values("number sizes", %w(1 2 3 4))
end

let(:product1) { create(:product, name: 'product1') }

it "should have variants" do
  hash = {number_size_option_type.id.to_s => number_size_option_type.option_value_ids}
  product1.option_values_hash = hash
  product1.save
  product1.reload
  expect(product1.variants.length).to eq(4)
end
```

no matter what i do, the number of variants for my product is always zero.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the product.option_values_hash needs to be added during product creation in order to invoke the variant creation code. here is the changed line and then i removed the hash from the test "should have variant"

```
let(:product1) { create(:product, name: 'product1', option_values_hash: {number_size_option_type.id.to_s => number_size_option_type.option_value_ids}) }

it "should have variants" do
  product1.save
  expect(product1.option_type_ids.length).to eq(1)
  expect(product1.variants.length).to eq(4)
end
```